# AngularJS: why can't I inject html in my view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm very very new to AngularJS and I saw some solutions on SO, but, due to my inexperience, I can't figure out how to achieve my task with those solutions, so I'm asking for help, please bear with me. Basically, as my question says, I need to inject and render some HTML in my view. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<tabset panel-tabs="true" panel-class="panel-grape" ng-controller="MainController" data-heading="OTHER NEWS">
   <div ng-repeat="tab in baseString" ng-bind-html-unsafe="tab">

    </div>

</tabset>
```

and my part of the **CONTROLLER:**

```
function createBase() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.news.news[0].posizioni.length; i++) {
        // $scope.tabsName[i] = $scope.news.news[0].posizioni[i][i];
    $scope.baseString[i] =["<tab heading='" + $scope.news.news[0].posizioni[i][i] + "' ng-controller='MainController'><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6' id='colonaDx"+ $scope.news.news[0].posizioni[i][i] +"'></div><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6' id='colonaSx"+ $scope.news.news[0].posizioni[i][i] +"'></div><div id='paginaz"+ $scope.news.news[0].posizioni[i][i] +"'></div></tab>"];
    }
}
```

I need that tabsName remain an array.

Over the last few hours, I have tried several solutions, but so far I'm not able to obtain any results...please can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT**
for better understanding the number of tab header depends on the results from a json:

**PORTION OF JSON:**

```
    {
   "news":[
      {
         "posizioni":[
            {
               "0":"allNews"
            },
            {
               "1":"SecondTab"
            }
         ]
       }
]
}
```

Comment: what version of Angular are you using? And what exactly isn't working?

Comment: To clarify, `ng-bind-html-unsafe` was removed in Angular 1.2. It's just `ng-bind-html` now. You may need to use `$sce.trustAsHtml()` on your html string before passing it to `ng-bind-html-unsafe`.

Comment: @DanPantry so if I'm using the v1.2.20 what do I have to do?

Comment: @DanPantry if I change to ng-bind-html it throw me this error:  TypeError: html.match is not a function

Comment: Wait wait wait ! You shoudn't need to inject html into your html via your controller. That's really really not an angular way to do that. Could you describe what you try to achieve in term of functionality ? (not technically)

Comment: @Okazari i need to create dynamically some tabs depending on how many there are in an object that comes from a Json.. that's why in my string I have that kind of Html..

Comment: Ok, you should use a ng-repeat then. You don't need to manipulate any html in a controller. The angular directives are there to manipuate HTML and create it dynamically, i'll build you an exemple and post it as an answer.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of this Json ?

Comment: @Okazari I edited my question with a portion of the Json

Comment: seems like you need just move this html from controller to your html

Comment: @Grundy I can't understand what are you trying to sa to me can you please provide me an example based on my code provided here? thanks

Comment: That teaches me to not actually read the entire question

Comment: what tab you use? [angular-ui/tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs)?

Comment: Have you got the hand on the JSON ? Because actually the json is quite strange. the posizioni should be a collection of objects with normalized names (like :  posizioni = [{name: thename},{name:thename2}] or it should just be a collection (like : posizioni = [thename,thename2]). Actually the collection of objects with dynamic properties (0,1,2) make it impossible to iterate.

Comment: @Okazari you can itarate trough in that way scope.news.news[0].posizioni[i][i]

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, HTML in your controller is a red flag; it's the wrong place.

Instead, use `ng-repeat`, close to what you tried, to build the HTML, [here's a quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/rreboto/qymqjfa3/7/).

In your controller, simply keep the *data*:

```
$scope.data = {
    "news": [
        {"posizioni": [
            {"0": "allNews"},
            {"1": "SecondTab"},
        ]}
    ]
};
```

In the HTML, your `ng-repeat` can look like this; because of the JSON structure above it gets a little messy, but it gets the job done:

```
<tab ng-repeat="(key, name) in data['news'][0]['posizioni']" heading="{{ tab.key }}" ng-click="selectTab($event, key, name)">{{ name[key] }}</tab>
```

In the fiddle I added a click handler to show how you can react to the click that happened in the TabController to update data in the ContentController through a Service.  Note, the ContentService contains an array of data, but you could update this to dynamically request the content from the upstream server:

```
$scope.selectTab = function (event, key, name) {
    ContentService.setContent(key);
}
```

Comment: That's the point, but regarding to his JSON he actually can't use a ng-repeat with it. Or at least not a clean one. Just try with his sample and tell me if you find a way.

Comment: Great job, still i woudn't recommend at all to use $broadcast even more on $root. To share data between controllers you should provide an exemple with services. Despite the fact that $broadcast works, it is not a good practice.

Comment: @berto Thanks I will try to implement it! Anyway sei Italiano, se ti lascio la mia email sarebbe inopportuno per te sentirci velocemente per telefono?

Comment: @FabioEnne Here is the same behavior with a traditional angular way to do it : Sharing data with a service (TabService) http://jsfiddle.net/z1otuffj/

Comment: Can you explain why it's bad practice to use `$broadcast` and why a service is better?  Fiddle updated to use a service instead. Updating the answer now.

Comment: @berto Had an argument about this on an other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670104/angularjs-broadcast-and-on-not-updating-scope/30670622#30670622 Here is my final explanation : "As far as i know $broadcast is more technically used in directives. Its use in controllers is not really necessary. I'd admit that if you really send events you could use it. But actually all the events are already wrapped in angular directives (ng-click, ng-enter etc...) and if it's just a matter of updating var from one controller to another, i would definitly go with the service shared variable."

Comment: @berto I would also just say, it's a matter of maintainability. $broadcast events can be catch at mutiple place in you code and $broadcast really make it hard to know what is happening. A service will centralise the data for a lot of things (Controllers, Other services, directives etc...) just with a dependency injection. Which is a lot more clear and leads to less mistakes.

Comment: @Okazari, thanks for the explanations; I agree using a Service is better.

Comment: @berto era solo per spiegarti cosa esattamente dovevo fare per lavoro, e due consigli più veloci per il lavoro che dovevo fare, ma se non ti va capiso, nessun problema era solo che sono nelle curve e devo finire il progetto per lunedi

Answer (score 0):

just move html string from your controller to your html like

```
<tabset panel-tabs="true" panel-class="panel-grape" ng-controller="MainController" data-heading="OTHER NEWS">
    <tab  ng-repeat="tab in news.news[0]" heading='{{tab[$index]}}' ng-controller='MainController'>
        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6' id='colonaDx{{tab[$index]}}'></div>
        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6' id='colonaSx{{tab[$index]}}'></div>
        <div id='paginaz{{tab[$index]}}'></div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```